# Proving that for a set $U\subset C$, $U$ is open if and only if for all $x \in U$, there exists a region $R$ such that $x \in R \subset U$.

Tags: calculus, general-topology

> Prove that for a set $U\subset C$, $U$ is open if and only if for all $x \in U$, there exists a region $R$ such that $x \in R \subset U$.

I just have no idea how to start and was wondering if anyone could maybe help me at least get started or get an idea on the intuition behind this theorem? I'm having trouble even visualizing why it would be true. Thanks!

The definition for an open set used in class is that a set $U$ is open if the complement $C\setminus U$ is closed where $C$ is the continuum.

The continuum is defined as being non-empty, having no first or last point, and having an ordering $<$. A closed set is one that contains all of its limit points and a region (a,b) is a set containing all points $x$ between a and b.

Comment: I think I have to somehow connect the region $R$ existing with the complement $C\setminus U$ being closed, but not sure how I would go about doing so.

Comment: Some definitions are not clear here. What do you mean by the *continuum* $C$: the real numbers? What is a *region*: an open interval? What is the definition of *closed* in your class: a set that contains all its limit points? As written your question is too vague and confusing.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the idea of the proof: show the contrapositive.

Take an $x \in U$  such that for every open interval $R$ that contains $x$ we have $R \not \subset U$. This means that $x$ is a limit point of $C\setminus U$ without $x$ in $C\setminus U$. This means that $C\setminus U$ is not closed, so $U$ is not open.

Can you fill in the details?

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! I'm having a bit of trouble seeing how the first sentence implies that x is a limit point of the complement of U however? I think it has something to do with every region R having an $x\in R$ and a $y\in C\setminus U$ but I can't figure out how that connects with the definition of a limit point. Thanks again!

Comment: @Twis7ed: I do not know what your particular definition of limit point is. But in some books, a limit point of a set is a point for which every open interval containing the point also contains another point in the set. That definition leads directly to $x$ is a limit point of $C\setminus U$. What is your given definition of limit point?